# Error trying to share CKRecord in Default Zone CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, share, cloudkit

I'm trying to use the shared Database in CloudKit.

As soon as I try to share a CKRecord, I get the error "Shares cannot exist in the default zone". 
I guess it's just a minor error on my side but, I have no clue for what I should look out for.

That's the error I get:

- Shares cannot exist in the default zone
- Can't share records in the default zone

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord/1640378-share?language=objc) say:

> Sharing is only supported in zones with the
>   CKRecordZoneCapabilitySharing capability. The default zone does not
>   support sharing.

This means, you have to define your custom zone that allows sharing records.